WPF MVVM Navigation View. Problem Continue creating view instances
What I want to implement is that when I click the button, the View switches.
However, View Instance will continue to create the whenever switch the Viewmodel.
I only want to create and reuse View Instance for the first time.
Is there a much used and good way to do it without code-Behind without violating MVVM?
App.xaml ↓
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RedViewModel}">
        <v:RedUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BlueViewModel}">
        <v:BlueUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>

MainWindow.xaml ↓
<Window x:Class="NavigationView.MainWindow"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:NavigationView.ViewModel">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Red UserControl" Command="{Binding RedCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Blue UserControl" Command="{Binding BlueCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ContentView}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindowViewModel.cs ↓
namespace NavigationView.ViewModel
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ViewModelManager _viewModelManager;

        private object _contentView;
        public object ContentView
        {
            get { return _contentView; }
            set { _contentView = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public ICommand RedCommand { get; set; }
        public void Red(object obj)
        {
            ContentView = _viewModelManager._redViewModel;
        }
        public ICommand BlueCommand { get; set; }
        public void Blue(object obj)
        {
            ContentView = _viewModelManager._blueViewModel;
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _viewModelManager = new ViewModelManager();

            RedCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Red);
            BlueCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Blue);

            ContentView = _viewModelManager._redViewModel;
        }
    }
}

RedUserControl.xaml ↓
<UserControl x:Class="NavigationView.View.RedUserControl"
             Background="Red">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

RedViewModel.cs ↓
namespace NavigationView.ViewModel
{
    public class RedViewModel
    {
        public RedViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
}

BlueUserControl.xaml ↓
<UserControl x:Class="NavigationView.View.BlueUserControl"
             Background="Blue">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

BlueViewModel.cs ↓
namespace NavigationView.ViewModel
{
    public class BlueViewModel
    {
        public BlueViewModel()
        {
        }
    }
}

ViewModelManager.cs ↓
namespace NavigationView.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelManager
    {
        public RedViewModel _redViewModel;
        public BlueViewModel _blueViewModel;

        public ViewModelManager()
        {
            _redViewModel = new RedViewModel();
            _blueViewModel = new BlueViewModel();
        }
    }
}

When you set up DataTemplate, you found the reason why View Instance continues to be created.
I've been stuck in this area for a few days, so I can't proceed at all.
I hope the masters and experienced people will help me.
Thank you

Hi, welcome to SO! You might want to look for DataTemplateSelector.

Fields are usually never public. If you need a public variable it must be a property. In your case that property should be read-only. Your code will look much better and more homogeneous with the framework and .NET library code.

You can also save a lot of extra code if you use a single command for the navigation and pass the destination as CommandParameter (e.g. an enum). This way you don't have to create a new command and command delegates for every view.

Why do you want to retain views? If you use viewmodel first then it's common to retain any state you need for a view in a viewmodel. If you somehow have view state does not suit this then you could consider pages and view first navigation instead of user controls and viewmodel first.

You can't reuse views if you simply provide them via DataTemplate. This is, because a DataTemplate is not reused. It's a template that instructs the XAML parser what object it has to create.
What you can do is to define the view itself as a static resource and then reference it from within the DataTemplate. Note that this resource can only be used once at the same time (an instance of UIElement can only exist in one place in the visual tree at the same time):
<Application.Resources>
  <RedUserControl x:Key="RedUserControl" />
  <BlueUserControl x:Key="RedUserControl" />

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RedViewModel}">
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource RedUserControl}" />
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BlueViewModel}">
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource BlueUserControl}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>

Be aware that your desired approach results in all views being kept in memory! If those views are complex, with a deep and complex reference graph, then this could be very expensive as the complete graph is kept alive.
Same applies to the view model instances.
Recreating views and view models could be cheaper than reusing them. If a view has a data state, this state should be maintained in dedicated model classes (cacheing). Then when instantiating a view model class you can use this cache model to initialize it.
This saves some valuale user system resources.
If loading time is an issue, consider initializing your view models asynchronously (after construction and triggering the view to load).
If this still doesn't satisfy the experience, reusing the slow components and dynamically adding them to the recreated main component may be the solution.
WPF also supports cacheing of views by using the BitmapCache class.
